# Turning line in notepad into an array

Tags: python

I am creating a program what takes a code and searches for a line in a product database notepad, once found it will sort the array in a certain fashion that when combined with other lines, it looks like a receipt.

```
for line in productDatabase:
    if requestedProduct in line:
        foundVariable = True
```

This block of code searches the lines in the notepad for the code. I need to figure out how then to turn that specific line into an array to be used later.

Here's the whole code.

```
exitDecision = int(input("Are you done? 1 = yes, 2 = no: "))

while exitDecision == 2:
    requestedProduct = input("Enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you want to buy: ")
    requestedProductQuantity = input("Enter the quantity of the product: ")
    productDatabase = open("productDatabase.txt","r")
    foundVariable = False
    for line in productDatabase:
        if requestedProduct in line:
            foundVariable = True


    if foundVariable == True:
        #Code to sort the line goes here.
    else:   
        #Code to sort the line if the product isn't found goes here.
```

Here's the notepad data.

```
29471829,milk,0.99
94726596,bread,1.20
26562636,paracetamol,2.99
45614621,Coca Cola,0.99
38192471,Butter,0.80
```

Comment: what do you mean when you want to turn a line into an array ?
`blaFoo into Array[0]=b Array[1]=l, Array[4]=o` ?

Comment: As in normally when you turn a line read from a notepad into an array, each seperated bit of data will be put into an array like this: [29471829,milk,0.99]

Comment: What's a 'notepad'?  Is it just another name for a file?

Comment: A text file, yes.

Answer (score 0):

When you check if the product is in line with `if requestedProduct in line:`, the `line` contains the line you want, you just have to split it

```
array=[]    

for line in productDatabase:
    if requestedProduct in line:
      array.append(line.split(','))
```

Comment: Why not only `line.split(',')`?

Comment: Yes, of course. But there is no need for a list comprehension,  `array = line.split(',')`. Especially as "there are no blankspace" in the data that was provided.

Comment: I know how to use `line.split`, but the problem I'm having is how do I define the exact line I need splitting?

 If I put it in 
`for line in productDatabase:
        if requestedProduct in line:
            foundVariable = True`
will it just split the line it finds the requestedProduct in?